# Rails: Multiple or conditions in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables: Lawyer and Phone. Phone is separated into area code and number. A lawyer has many phones. I want to produce a query that searches for lawyers who have a phone matching a phone from a list of phones.

If I had only one phone I could search it like this:

```ruby
Lawyer.join(:phones).where(:area_code => area_code, :number => number)
```

The problem is that I have a list with more than one area code. So I really want to do something like this:

```ruby
lawyers = []
phones.each { |phone| lawyers += Lawyer.join(:phones).where(:area_code => phone[:area_code], :number => phone[:number]) }
```

However, I don't want to make many queries. Can't it be done in a single query statement?

Edit: This is how I would do a similar thing using SQL alone (assuming the list of numbers was [{:area_code=>'555', :number=>'1234564'}, {:area_code=>'533', :number=>'12345678'}])

```sql
select * from phones where (area_code, number) in (('555', '1234564'), ('533', '12345678'))
```

If someone can get that translated into ActiveRecord, that'd be great.

Answer (score 19):

If you pass an array of area_codes, AR will build an IN condition.  So you could use your original search and use arrays instead:

where area_codes is an array of area_codes and numbers an array of numbers:

```
 Lawyer.join(:phones).where(:area_code => area_codes, :number => numbers)
```

or:

```
 Lawyer.join(:phones).where("phones.area_code IN (?) AND phones.number IN (?)", area_codes, numbers)
```

Should yield:

```
 SELECT * from lawyers JOIN phones ON phones.lawyer_id = lawyers.id WHERE phones.area_code IN (...) AND phones.number IN (...)
```

Comment: I thought about that, but it doesn't work exactly like I want to. The problem is that two area codes could have the same telephone number. Let's say we are looking for two phones: [{:area_code=>555, :number=>5555555}, {:area_code=>444, :number=>12345678}]. If I use your approach, then a lawyer living in area code 444 with number 5555555 would match. I don't want that.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem now.  Personally, I'd "denormalize" the data into one column so it's more search friendly. Otherwise, I suppose you could build a where condition by looping each code and number, but I like that solution a lot less.

Comment: It's easy to do this in SQL: select * from phones where (area_code, number) in (('555', '5555555'), ('444','12345678')) So there's really no reason to denormalize data. All I need to do is how to translate that into ActiveRecord.

Comment: I think that last comment should have been your original question :-) Anyway, and in that case, I don't have a solid solution for you other than building the condition string with your criteria and using it in your where clause ex: Lawyer.joins(:phones).where("(area_code, number) IN (#{your_val_string})") - but that could leave you open to sql injection. Sorry - hope you can use this or find another acceptable soln.

Answer (score 5):

```
Lawyer.join(:phones).where(
  "(phones.area_code, phones.number) IN ( ('555', '5555555'), ('444', '12345678') )"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect ActiveRecord to support this syntax for us, but it's already been discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/g/rubyonrails-core/c/RnKkEwbcNCk/m/3AJz9UOy_d4J) and no action seems to have been taken. To work around the issue, you can use something like:

```rb
phone_numbers = [['555', '55555555'], ['444', '44444444'], ...]
placeholders = Array.new(phone_numbers.size, '(?)').join(', ')
Phone.where("(area_code, number) IN (#{placeholders}", *phone_numbers)
```